# Only One Combobox Databinding Can Be Handled In The Form Load Event

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have created a linq, and the result is to give me a list of itemtypes, and i tried to bind the list to the combobox, but it's very strange that after i set the DisplayMember and ValueMember for the first combobox, and then the load event seems to return, and never execute the rest of the codes

```
private void AddOpenOrderForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (context = new MRP_DBEntities())
    {

         var query1 = (from i in context.LookUPs select i.itemType).Distinct();
         itemType1CB.DataSource = query1.ToList();
         itemType1CB.DisplayMember = "itemType";
         itemType1CB.ValueMember = "itemType";

         MessageBox.Show("The program will not reach the follow codes");

         itemType2CB.DataSource = query1.ToList();
         itemType2CB.DisplayMember = "itemType";
         itemType2CB.ValueMember = "itemType";
      }


}
```

Comment: No exceptions? Nothing in the output? Are you able to step through with a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're getting an exception that you're just not seeing. You're already *selecting* the `itemType` member here:

```
var query1 = (from i in context.LookUPs select i.itemType).Distinct();
```

... but then you're trying to find the `itemType` member of each value here:

```
itemType1CB.DisplayMember = "itemType";
itemType1CB.ValueMember = "itemType";
```

I suspect you should just leave the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` as `""` so that you're displaying the objects themselves.

I would also suggest calling `ToList` *once*, and not using a query expression where it's not really reducing clutter:

```
 var list = context.LookUPs.Select(i => i.itemType).Distinct().ToList();
 itemType1CB.DataSource = list;
 itemType2CB.DataSource = list;

 // Unless you've set the display/value members elsewhere, they'll default to ""
```

Comment: yes, it works, but should I get rid of  itemType1CB.DisplayMember = "itemType";
itemType1CB.ValueMember = "itemType";  since I only selecting the itemType

Comment: @user1286824: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say.